# Adobe Reader does not display borderstyle=U Textfields

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, forms

In relation to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447460/latex-forms-transfer-textfield-border-into-line/447490?noredirect=1#comment1143595_447490), I just discovered, that the official Adobe Reader doesn't display TextFields, which have the flag borderstyle=U set.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \TextField[width=0.98\linewidth,bordercolor={0 0 0},charsize=0pt,borderstyle=U]{}\\
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Display as expected in evince, not at all in Adobe Reader (Windows 10).

Any ideas?

PS: Exact version is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Version 2018.009.20044.
PPS: Also tested in Adobe Acrobat **Pro** DC Version 2015.006.30033

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the `borderstyle`, it is the empty field name. A text field without name is dropped by Adobe Reader, so you either have to use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \TextField[width=0.98\linewidth,bordercolor={0 0 0},charsize=0pt,borderstyle=U]{Some name}\\% <-- Insert a nice name here, it will be printed next to the field
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

or, if you do not want the fieldname to be shown next to the field, use the `name=` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
  \TextField[name=SOME_UNIQUE_NAME,width=0.98\linewidth,bordercolor={0 0 0},charsize=0pt,borderstyle=U]{}\\
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution with setting a name is really convenient. It works except in ”Preview“ on MacOS 10.9.5. I haven't had a chance to test more recent MacOS versions yet.